# Google map api v3 Show coordinates while draw polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I noticed that I can take the coordinates of a polyline only after the polyline is completed:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', function (...)
```

Is there a way to get the coordinates of the polyline while I draw it?

Comment: Could you add more code or link to a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing your polyline manually (with your mouse) You can get the coordinates of your cursor while moving it over the map:

**Mousemove:**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
      document.getElementById('latitude').value = event.latLng.lat();
      document.getElementById('longitude').value = event.latLng.lng();
});
```

HTML: `<input type="text" id="longitude"><input type="text" id="longitude">`